# javascript code of picking td value from the screenshot below

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-table, element

From the screenshot below, two questions as newbie of javascript developer.
I want to directly get the value of the second td from `$('#cart-subtotal-order.total.subtotal td')` in javascript code. That is the first question. The second question is how to get the value of `$('.amount grand-total')`. Is it right to use `val()` for that like this `$('.amount grand-total').val()` or should I use `text()` for the regular text value for that?

[HTML Body elements source screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hkFl.png)

Comment: Please never post code as an image. And usually we want to see how you tried to solve this instead of asking only a question ;-)

Comment: `.val()` gets/sets the value of an input element and `.text()` gets/sets the text of an HTML element, so in your case there are no input elements and therfore use `.text()`

Answer (score 1):

**if you wat to get second td from tr:**

```
var subtotal = $('#cart-subtotal-order.total.subtotal').find("td:eq(1)").text();
```

**then if you want to get grand total is like:**

```
var grand_total = $('#totalRow .grand-total').text();
```

Answer (score 1):

**For Getting Second row text, you can use the following code**

```
var seondRow =  $("table>#cart-subtotal-order.total.subtotal> td:nth-child(2)").text();
```

**For Getting the grand total**

```
var grandTotal = $('#totalRow .grand-total').text();
```

or

```
var grandTotal = $('#totalRow .grand-total').value();
```